# Turning a product into a sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, summation, products

Is it possible to change $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+2a_ib_i),$$ where all elements are contained in an unital associative algebra generated by $a_i,b_i$, $i=1,...,n$, such that $a_ib_i=-b_ia_i$, into a sum which contains the summand $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2a_ib_i?$$

There is no special background for this question it is just about what I am asking.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you take logs since $$\ln\left(\prod_k (1+a_k)\right) = \sum_k \ln (1+a_k)$$ and then expand $\ln(1+a_k)$ in series using $$\ln(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3 \pm \ldots$$

Comment: You can expand it by brute force so that the first term (out of a total of $2^n$) is$1$ and the next $n$ terms are those that you want.  Subsequent terms would be straightforward if the algebra was communitative.  However in your case you need to take into acount the order for terms like $4a_ib_ia_jb_j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is.

Have a look at the case $n = 2$:

$(1 + 2a_1b_1)(1 + 2a_2 b_2) = 1 + 2a_1b_1 + 2a_2 b_2 + 4a_1b_1a_2b_2; \tag 1$

have a look at the case $n = 3$:

$(1 + 2a_1b_1)(1 + 2a_2 b_2)(1 + 2a_3 b_3) = (1 + 2a_1b_1 + 2a_2 b_2 + 4a_1b_1a_2b_2)(1 + 2a_3 b_3)$
$= 1 +  2a_1b_1 + 2a_2 b_2 + 4a_1b_1a_2b_2$
$+ 2a_3b_3 + 4a_1b_1a_3b_3 + 4a_2b_2a_3b_3 + 8a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3$
$= 1 +  2a_1b_1 + 2a_2 b_2 + 2a_3b_3 + 4a_1b_1a_2b_2$
$+ 4a_1b_1a_3b_3 + 4a_2b_2a_3b_3 + 8a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3; \tag 2$

we can proceed by induction;  suppose we simplify notation by settig

$c_i = a_ib_i; \tag 3$

then we already have

$(1 + 2c_1)(1 + 2c_2) = 1 + 2c_1 + 2c_2 + 4c_1c_2, \tag 4$

and

$(1 + 2c_1)(1 + 2c_2)(1 + 2c_3) = 1 + 2c_1 + 2c_2 + 2c_3$
$+ 4c_1c_2 + 4c_1c_3 + 4c_2c_3 + 8c_1c_2c_3, \tag 5$

so we have established the $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ cases of

$\displaystyle \prod_1^n (1 + 2c_i) = 1 + \sum_1^n 2c_i + H_n, \tag 6$

where $H_n$ is just shorthand for the higher order terms in $\prod_1^n(1 + 2c_i)$, i.e., the ones of degree at least two in the $c_i = a_i b_i$; now if

$\displaystyle \prod_1^k (1 + 2c_i) = 1 + \sum_1^k 2c_i + H_k, \tag 7$

then

$\displaystyle \prod_1^{k + 1} (1 + 2c_i) = \left (  \prod_1^k (1 + 2c_i) \right )(1 + 2c_{k + 1}) = (1 + \displaystyle \sum_1^k 2c_i + H_k)(1 + 2c_{k + 1})$
$= 1 +  \displaystyle \sum_1^k 2c_i + H_k + 2c_{k + 1} + \left ( \sum_1^k 2c_i \right )2c_{k + 1} + 2H_k c_{k + 1}$
$= 1 + \displaystyle \sum_1^{k + 1} 2c_i + H_k + 2\sum_1^k c_i c_{k + 1} +  2H_kc_{k + 1} = 1 + \sum_1^{k + 1} 2c_i + H_{k + 1}, \tag 8$

which completes the induction and shows that (6) holds for all $n$.

Note that the property $a_ib_i = -b_ia_i$ was not needed here.

Comment: Thank you that helps! can you give an explicit form for $H_n$?

Comment: @user114179:  you can read it off from (8), if you can settle for an inductive definition:  $H_{k + 1} = H_k + 2\sum_1^k c_i c_{k + 1} + 2H_kc_{k + 1}$; if you look at it carefully, you can see that this accounts for all the terms.  You can also write out the $H_k$ as a sum of the form $4\sum_{i, j = 1; i < j}^k c_ic_j+ 8\sum_{i, h, k = 1; i < j < l}^k c_ic_jc_l + \ldots$.  Maybe you can take it from here, it's not hard, but writing it down is sort of a chore.  Cheers!

Comment: @user114179:  that looks right  I don't see where I allowed the $c_i$ to commute, though . . . because the conditions like $i < j$ enforce the order ot the $c_i$.  Do they commute?

Comment: @user114179:  but I didn't want to assume *any* of the variables commuted.  I assumed not.

Comment: In you problem you only said $a_ib_i = -b_ia_i$, nothing more.  So I assumed nothing more.

Comment: @user114179:  shoot me a message here with a link to it when you post!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with problems like this it is useful to consider small examples. This product depends on $n$, so let's look at $n=2,3,\ldots$:

For $n=2$, we have
$$
(1+2a_1b_1)(1+2a_2b_2)=1+(2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2)+4a_1b_1a_2b_2
$$
by "foiling". For $n=3$,
\begin{align}
(1+2a_1b_1)(1+2a_2b_2)(1+2a_3b_3)=&(1+(2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2)+4a_1b_1a_2b_2)(1+2a_3b_3)\\
=&[1+(2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2)+4a_1b_1a_2b_2]\\&+[2a_3b_3+(2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2)(2a_3b_3)+(4a_1b_1a_2b_2)(2a_3b_3)]\\
=&1+(2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2+2a_3b_3)\\&+4(a_1b_1a_2b_2+a_1b_1a_3b_3+a_2b_2a_3b_3)+8a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3.
\end{align}
Perhaps you can finish from here.

Comment: Have you used commutativity or not? I wonder why e.g. in the $n=3$ case there is no term like $a_2b_2a_1b_1$.

Comment: There is no commutativity in the statement of the problem, and no term like that appears in the product.. Note that the term $(1+2a_1b_1)$ is to the left of $(1+2a_2b_2)$. Everything is multiplied out in order.

Comment: You are right, I thought wrong. Thank you!